# Variable incrementing in bash

Tags: linux, bash, variables

Consider the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

num=0
cat file | while read line; do
    echo "$line"
    lines[$num]="$line"
    ((num++))
    echo "num = $num"
done

echo "end num = $num"

i=0
while [ $i -lt $num ]; do
    echo "${lines[$i]}"
    ((i++))
done
```

Normally, it should read the file line by line, store the result in an array, then go through the array and print it line by line. The problem is that the variable $num resets somehow after the first loop exits. The output of this script for me is the following (using a file with some random garbage in it):

```
dsfkljhhsdfsdfshdjkfgd
num = 1
fdfgdfgdfg
num = 2
dfgdfgdfgdfg
num = 3
dfgdfgdfgdfgdfg
num = 4
dfgdfgdfgdfgdfgd
num = 5
fgdfgdfgdfg
num = 6
dfgdfgdfgdfg
num = 7
dfgdfgdfgdfgdfg
num = 8
dfgdfgdfgdfg
num = 9
dfgdfgdgdgdg
num = 10
dfgdffgdgdgdg
num = 11
end num = 0
```

Why is this? How do I achieve to remember the variable? I am using bash 3.1.17 on SUSE Linux 10.

Comment: Probably the problem is the pipe. Using standard input does not show the problem: https://ideone.com/87yi6

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why? It's because this:

```
cat file | while read line; do
    echo "$line"
    lines[$num]="$line"
    ((num++))
    echo "num = $num"
done
```

runs the `while` statement in a separate process, with its own environment, not touching the parent environment. You'll find, similarly, that the `lines` array is not there either.

The following simplified script shows this in action:

```
#!/bin/bash
export xyzzy=42
echo urk | while read line; do
    xyzzy=999
    echo $xyzzy
done
echo $xyzzy
```

The output of that script is:

```
999
42
```

because the setting of the variable to `999` is done in the subprocess.

Bottom line, if you want information to be reflected in the current process (the script), you'll need to do the work *in* the script or find some other way to get the information out of the sub-process.

If you use input redirection rather than starting a sub-process pipeline, it should work as you want. That's because the `while` bit is then done in the context of the *current* process rather than a separate process in a pipeline. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
export xyzzy=42
while read line; do
    xyzzy=999
    echo $xyzzy
done <<EOF
hello
EOF
echo $xyzzy
```

will produce:

```
999
999
```

For your specific case, replace:

```
done <<EOF
hello
EOF
```

with:

```
done <file
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to the previous answer: and to avoid that (and the UUOC), you'll need something like this:

```
while ...; do
  ...
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply keep your variables all in the same environment.  On line 4, remove "cat file | ".  On line 9, append " < file".  Your end num will now contain the expected 11, and the lines array will print one element at a time via your second loop.